# Need RegEx for evaluating hyphen separated value where first limit should be always less than second limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

i have wriiten a regular expression,which allows a range of numbersseparated by camma's and can have hyphen separated values,can have * also  but i need my regex to support all the hyphen seperated values where first limit should be always less than second limit like 10-20,40-50 but not 60-20

```
var regex = /^(\*|(\d+(\-(\d+|\*))?)(\,(\d+(\-(\d+|\*))?))*)(?!(\*\,))$/g;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I doubt that could be done easily with regex, as this goes over an LL1 syntax, any way, please do not hesitate to add some more clarifications to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you want to solve is not solvable with a regular expression because you do not descripe a regular language. But you could use a regular expression to first validate if the format is correct and then split your input and manually do the validation of the values you want to compare.

Comment: The approach you suggest is good, but the reason you invoke is wrong. This has nothing to do with the fact the language is regular or not, this kind of arguments is more for computer sciences and is only applicable today for very basic regex engines. Regular expressions in computer sciences and regular expressions in practise are two different things. The main problem is when you repeat a capture group with the JS regex engine, the previously captured content is deleted at the opening bracket *(when other engines overwrite it at the closing, see with php: https://regex101.com/r/mK8cE5/1)*

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to split the source string into elements (using the `split` method of strings using `,` as the separator, and then loop over each element and split again using `-` as separator and compare the min and max values.

This is a little more code to write, but something that you will still understand in 2 years when you  will need to re-read your code.